# How to download an image with a Java socket HTTP/1.1 request?

Tags: java, image, sockets, http

I am trying to download images using `java.net.Socket` without `java.net.URL` and external libraries. Here is what I have and I am not sure what isn't working.

```
        String domain = "www.manchester.edu";
        String path = "/images/default-source/default-album/slide1.jpg";
        Socket socket = new Socket(domain,80);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
        out.println("" +
                "Get "+path+" HTTP/1.1\n" +
                "Host: "+domain+"\n"+
                "");
        out.println();
        out.flush();

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());
```

In order to see what is coming through the stream, exchange the `BufferedImage` line for:

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null && inputLine.trim() != "0") {
       System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
```

Presumably the `ImageIO.read(...)` method does not expect the HTTP header in the socket input stream. But I am not sure how to remove the header. I've tried reading the header lines with `BufferedReader` and then passing the socket input stream to `ImageIO.read(...)` but that did not work.

Here is the string printed by `BufferedReader`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=7776000
Content-Length: 96876
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Expires: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 21:36:46 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 14:23:40 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
content-disposition: inline; filename=slide1.jpg
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2015 21:36:46 GMT

����...
```

The non-printable characters at the end seems to indicate that what follows the header is an image of some sort. But how can I turn this into a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` or a `javafx.scene.image.Image`? The latter has a constructor that takes an input stream, and I've tried that, but it doesn't work (because of the http header?). This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27013834/5103963) one, but I am trying to create an image not a file.

Comment: Have you tried using ImageInputStream instead of InputStream?

Comment: Why? Why not use `HttpURLConnection`  and save yourself a lot of bother? A ***lot*** of bother. You're going to have to deal with content-length, content-encoding, HTTP 1.0, ...

Comment: @Luis How to can I get an ImageInputStream? I've tried type casting the `socket.getInputStream` but that doesn't work.

Comment: @EJP Could I get an `HttpURLConnection` from a socket? I would like to avoid bother, but I am trying to figure out how to get an image using sockets and HTTP requests. (My goal is to learn)

Comment: No, you can't do that, you get it from a URL. The suggestion about an ImageInputStream doesn't add much to what you're already doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `BufferedReader` is a mistake for 2 reasons:

1. It converts bytes to a `String` which you then convert back into bytes to send it into the output stream. The conversions may (and probably will) lead to loss of data;
2. It parses too many bytes and you have no control over it.

You need to approach this surgically, creating a buffer of bytes of the size you want and using an `InputStream` to read the stream byte-by-byte on your own terms. Also, since you know that the HTTP header ending is "\r\n\r\n" (or 13 10 13 10 in bytes), you can scan your own buffer for this pattern and act accordingly.

Your best bet is to download the image to a file and then use the ImageIO to read it from the local file.

## Here's the code that will allow you to download an Image file (or any other file) by cutting out the header:

```
    // Initialize the streams.
    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    final InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

    // Header end flag.
    boolean headerEnded = false;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        // If the end of the header had already been reached, write the bytes to the file as normal.
        if (headerEnded)
            fileOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, length);

        // This locates the end of the header by comparing the current byte as well as the next 3 bytes
        // with the HTTP header end "\r\n\r\n" (which in integer representation would be 13 10 13 10).
        // If the end of the header is reached, the flag is set to true and the remaining data in the
        // currently buffered byte array is written into the file.
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2045; i++) {
                if (bytes[i] == 13 && bytes[i + 1] == 10 && bytes[i + 2] == 13 && bytes[i + 3] == 10) {
                    headerEnded = true;
                    fileOutputStream.write(bytes, i+4 , 2048-i-4);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    inputStream.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: This code assumes that the two adjacent CRLFs all arrive in the same read.

Comment: @EJP The buffer size may be increased as needed.